# How To Delete Extra Worksheet In Excel Using JavaScript/ActiveX

Tags: javascript, excel

I am trying to delete 2nd excel sheet with the following

```
var objExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var objWorkbook = objExcel.WorkBooks.Add;
var objWorkSheet = objWorkbook.WorkSheets(1);
objWorkSheet.Paste //Working fine
objWorkbook.WorkSheets(2)->Select;
objWorkbook.WorkSheets(2)->Delete;
```

I can successfully paste to the first worksheet, 
But I get a Syntax error for the last 2 lines from javascript.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Select()` and `Delete()` are methods and need the brackets after their names.

Comment: That is not it.Its still throwing syntax error. Moreover Paste is a method which does not have brackets and works good

Comment: OK. What happens if you try: `objWorkSheet = objWorkbook.WorkSheets(2); objWorkSheet.Select; objWorkSheet.Delete;` ? Also please check the semi-colons - your `.Paste` line does not end in a semi-colon where your other lines do, is this intentional?

Comment: Sorry abt the missing the semicolon after Paste. It is there in the original code. I tried assigning worksheet to a variable, objWorkSheet = objWorkbook.WorkSheets(2),  still same syntax error

Comment: I just ran it through http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php for you. If you replace the `->` with `.` it does not give syntax errors.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks a lot for the trouble. Sorry I can't tick your answer since I don't have enough reputation :-(

Comment: Glad it helped. The act of accepting answers shouldn't be limited by reputation - I think the only limit is you can't accept an answer within the first 15 minutes of asking the question. See here for more info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thanks I just accepted your answer. It was your comment that actually helped me.